# jumping ID aunto increment after delete

Tags: mysql, cakephp-3.7

When I was delete record Users, the ID primary key auto increment always jumping, I want ID auto increment is sequence again, this sample

```
|  ID  |  UserName |
|   1  |   Budi    |
|   2  |   Joko    |    
|   3  |   Amir    |
```

when I delete users Joko, then I add new other user, the ID number is jumping

```
|  ID  | UserName |
|  1   |   Budi   |
|  3   |   Amir   |
|  4   |   Faris  |
```

while I've browsing solution, I get some solution, but doesn't work.
here I've add modified file

```
config/app.php
```

```
'SQLkonek' => [
      'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
      'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
      'persistent' => false,
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'username' => 'root',
      'paassword' => ' ',
      'database' => 'klinikucing',
      'encoding' => 'utf8mb4',
      'timezone' => ' ',
      'cacheMetadata' => true
]
```

then I call modified above through

```
controller/UsersController.php
```

```
public function delete ($id = null)
{
   $this->request->allowMethod(['post', 'delete']);
   $kon = ConnectionManager::get('SQLkonek');
   $user = $this->Users->get($id);
   $stm = $kon->execute(array(
                  ['SET @count = 0'],
                  ['DELETE FROM users WHERE ID = :ID'],
                  ['UPDATE users SET users.ID = @count:= @count + 1'],
                  ['ALTER TABLE users AUTO_INCREMENT =1']
               ))
               ->fetchAll('assoc');
   If($this->Users->$stm) {
         $this->Flash->success(__('Users success delete.'));
   } else {
         $this->Flash->error(__('User delete failed, try again.'));
   }
   return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
}
```

The error message was shown

```
Warning (2): PDO::prepare() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given [CORE\src\Database\Driver\Mysql.php, line 138]
Warning (512): Unable to emit headers. Headers sent in file=C:\xampp\htdocs\klinikucing\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Error\Debugger.php line=853 [CORE\src\Http\ResponseEmitter.php, line 48]
Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\klinikucing\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Error\Debugger.php:853) [CORE\src\Http\ResponseEmitter.php, line 148
Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\klinikucing\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Error\Debugger.php:853) [CORE\src\Http\ResponseEmitter.php, line 181]
Argument 1 passed to Cake\Database\Statement\PDOStatement::__construct() must be an instance of PDOStatement or null, boolean given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\klinikucing\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Database\Driver\Mysql.php on line 139
Error in: ROOT\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Database\Statement\PDOStatement.php, line 33
```

My CakePHP version is 3.7.2
I hopefull that someone can help me, thanx

Answer (score 3):

Don't renumber. Accept there will be gaps in AI due to deleting an other cause (like aborted transaction, INSERT IGNORE etc.).

As you change PK values you change the FK relationships they have.

With ID of a type of `INT UNSIGNED` or `BIGINT UNSIGNED` you're not going to run out of ID ever.